# Log Ingestion on ES hosted on GCP

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I am recently started working on one task where I have to ingest data on ES hosted on GCP. Earlier It was AWS ES where I was having direct access of AWS ES. I am unable to do in GCP ES? has one done this so far? I tried google but struggling to get? I am new to GCP also.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch Service on GCP is a third party software and has its own support channel. Please reach out to Elastic Cloud Support at:

https://cloud.elastic.co/help or http://www.elastic.co/community/

If you are looking for ways to feed the logs stored in GCS buckets to you ElasticSearch cluster running on GKE, this is one of the plugins that I can find from a quick Google search:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-google_cloud_storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Just like AWS you have the option to have a managed ES cluster in GCP.
Check out the GCP market place for different offering:

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/elasticsearch?q=elasticsearch

A better option is to install the cluster manually in compute engine, this way you have better control on various settings and security feature since most of the ES features like Xpack security, Machine learning, APM etc are not available in OSS distribution.